# jsp error when using if-else with html

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have the following in my jsp page (assume that client is an object )

```
<%
 if( client == null)
 %>
NO client
 <% 
 else
%>
<a href='page.jsp?aid=<%=client.getID()%>'> and his name is  <%=client.getName()%>
```

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing the brackets:

```
<% if( client == null) {  %>
NO client
<% } else { %>
<a href='page.jsp?aid=<%=client.getID()%>'> and his name is  <%=client.getName()%>
<% } %>
```

That said, this is an example of bad JSP code. Consider using JSTL tags / expressions instead of scriptlets.

Answer (score 3):

in jstl it would be something similar to

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${client is null}">
NO client
  </c:when>
<c:otherwise>
  <A href="<c:url value="page.jsp" >
    <c:param name="aid" value="${client.ID}" />
           </c:url>" 
  > and his name is <c:out value="${client.name}"/>
</c:otherwise>
```